# controlling servo without servo.h library (speed issue)

Tags: arduino, servo

Iam trying to create my own code to control a servo without using the servo.h library,i was able to create the PWM signal using the code blow, and i was able to move to servo to any angle, but my issue is the speed, the servo has the same speed, iam building a robot and i want to control my speed. can some one help ? , i tried to use a delay but the speed is alway the same.

```
int pinservo =9;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

  pinMode(pinservo, OUTPUT);


}

void loop() {
 


for (int i=400;i<2500;i++){   // 400 micro-second for 0 degree, 2500 micro-seconds for 180 degree
    digitalWrite(pinservo,HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(i);
    digitalWrite(pinservo,LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(20000-(i));




}
```

Comment: Where did you try to put your `delay` statement?

Comment: outside the for loop

Comment: Put in inside the for loop and it will work.